# regular expression to replace anything but unicode letters in Java

Tags: java, regex

My text file is in the following format having different type of strings such as below:

```
candle
(air-paraffin)
1,000
°c
(1,800
°f)
smoldering
cigarette:
temperature
13%,
wildlife.[14]
johnston,
f.
h.;
keeley,
j.
bibcode:2009sci...324..481b
(http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009sci...3
```

I would like to remove everything except simple words such as the ones below.

```
smoldering
temperature
```

That is if a word is even followed by a comma (e.g. smoldering,), I would remove it.

I tried to remove the digits for a start with `MyString.replaceAll("^\\d", " ")` but even that is not working.

Comment: Could you edit your question to attach full output from that input? I can't understand if you want to remove `johnston,` or modify it to `johnston`

Comment: not modify but remove patterns like johnston, if it was johnston without the following comma I would have kept it.

Comment: So, do you want to keep lines with only letters?

Comment: yes. That's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the entire file into memory, with line breaks, you can use a regex like this:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)^.*[^a-zA-Z\r\n].*(?:\R|$)", "")
```

*Output*

```
candle
smoldering
temperature
```

For demo see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JLIXdR/1).

It would however be better to do the filtering while you load the text file:

```
Pattern simpleWord = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+"); // one or more Unicode letters
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("path/to/file.txt"))) {
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        if (simpleWord.matcher(line).matches()) {
            // found simple word
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the simple words in a list, you can simplify that with Java 8 stream:

```
List<String> simpleWords;
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("path/to/file.txt"))) {
    simpleWords = lines.filter(Pattern.compile("^\\p{L}+$").asPredicate())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: actually, the regex for unicode letter is such a simple but effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will iterate over the input.txt lines and paste them into output.txt if they match certain regex. After that it will remove output.txt and rename it with input.txt original file.

### Class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReplaceWithRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$", line)) {
                    writer.write(line);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
            }
        }
        if (inputFile.delete()) {
            // Rename the output file to the input file
            if (!outputFile.renameTo(inputFile)) {
                throw new IOException("Could not rename output to input");
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Could not delete original input file ");
        }
    }
}
```

### Input.txt

```
candle
(air-paraffin)
1,000
°c
(1,800
°f)
smoldering
cigarette:
temperature
13%,
wildlife.[14]
johnston,
f.
h.;
keeley,
j.
bibcode:2009sci...324..481b
(http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009sci...3
```

### Input.txt after execution:

```
candle
smoldering
temperature
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lines are delimiters:

```
myString.replaceAll("^[^a-z&&[^A-Z]]*$", "");
```

Comment: thanks but that's not working

Comment: removes the numbers though.

Comment: Why `[^a-z&&[^A-Z]]` and not just `[^a-zA-Z]`? The `^` applies to the entire character class.

Comment: Yes, but kzs says it doesn't work

Comment: That is because `^` and `$` only matches the beginning and end of the entire string, not each line in the string. Notice that OP has loaded entire text file into memory in the `MyString` variable.